# Different behavior using tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

I was making a image downloading project for a website, but I encountered some strange behavior using tqdm. In the code below I included two options for making the tqdm progress bar. In option one I did not passed the iteratable content from response into the tqdm directly, while the second option I did. Although the code looks similar, the result is strangely different.

[This is what the progress bar's result looks like using Option 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wFdI.png)

[This is what the progress bar's result looks like using Option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i3RN.png)

Option one is the result I desire but I just couldn't find an explanation for the behavior of using Option 2. Can anyone help me explain this behavior?

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

# Folder to store in
default_path = "D:\\Downloads"


def download_image(url):
    """

    This function will download the given url's image with proper filename labeling
    If a path is not provided the image will be downloaded to the Downloads folder
    """

    # Establish a Session with cookies
    s = requests.Session()

    # Fix for pixiv's request you have to add referer in order to download images
    response = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
                                   'referer': 'https://www.pixiv.net/'}, stream=True)

    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]  # Retrieve the file name of the link
    together = os.path.join(default_path, file_name)  # Join together path with the file_name. Where to store the file
    file_size = int(response.headers["Content-Length"])  # Get the total byte size of the file
    chunk_size = 1024  # Consuming in 1024 byte per chunk

    # Option 1
    progress = tqdm(total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc="Downloading {file}".format(file=file_name))

    # Open the file destination and write in binary mode
    with open(together, "wb") as f:
        # Loop through each of the chunks in response in chunk_size and update the progres by calling update using
        # len(chunk) not chunk_size
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size):
            f.write(chunk)

            progress.update(len(chunk))

    # Option 2
    """progress = tqdm(response.iter_content(chunk_size),total=file_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True, desc="Downloading {file}".format(file = file_name))

    with open(together, "wb") as f:

        for chunk in progress:

            progress.update(len(chunk))
            f.write(chunk)

    # Close the tqdm object and file object as good practice
    """

    progress.close()
    f.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    download_image("Image Link")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an existing bug with `tqdm`. https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/766

**Option 1:**

- Provides tqdm the total size
- On each iteration, update progress. Expect the progress bar to keep moving.
- Works fine.

**Option 2:**

- Provides tqdm the total size along with a **generator** function that tracks the progress.
- On each iteration, it should automatically get the update from generator and push the progress bar.
- However, you also call `progress.update` manually, which **should not be the case.**
- Instead let the generator do the job.
- But this doesn't work either, and the issue is already reported.

**Suggestion on Option 1:**
To avoid closing streams manually, you can enclose them inside `with` statement. Same applies to tqdm as well.

```py
# Open the file destination and write in binary mode
    with tqdm(total=file_size, 
        unit='B', 
        unit_scale=True, 
        desc="Downloading {file}".format(file=file_name)
    ) as progress, open(file_name, "wb") as f:
        # Loop through each of the chunks in response in chunk_size and update the progres by calling update using
        # len(chunk) not chunk_size
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size):
            progress.update(len(chunk))
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, guess I will just stick with option one along with your improvement! Thank you so much again!